# Python subprocess.call with variable substitution

Tags: python

The Code:

```
MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_LOCATION = '/tmp'
MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_FILE = 'filename.xml'
TEMP_DATA_FILE_LOCATION = '/tmp/other_location'
subprocess.call(["/bin/cp","-a","MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_LOCATION MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_FILE","TEMP_DATA_FILE_LOCATION"])
```

What do I put between `MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_LOCATION` and `MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_FILE` to put a `/` there?  I have tried various combinations without success.

What I want is to separate the two variables with a `/`, so that it reads `/tmp/filename.xml` by using variable substitution. I do not want to hardcode the paths or filenames as they are used throughout the script.

Comment: You have problems with your shift key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
subprocess.call(["/bin/cp", "-a",
    os.path.join(MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_LOCATION, MOST_POPULAR_REPORTS_FILE), 
        TEMP_DATA_FILE_LOCATION])
```

You should not put variable names in quotes, or you'll get string literals. This is not shell.

Comment: Excellent, just learning python and had not come across that module yet.  Figured there was a easy way of doing this.

Comment: @BruceJackson This is the right way for the specific use case (file names) as it is platform-aware. In general you can concatenate strings with `+`: `'spam' + ' and ' + 'eggs'` or use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for any number of strings with a common separator. P.S. Consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181223) the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: I had already tried the string concatenation with + without success.  Thanks for the pointer to os.path.join.  That was exactly what I was looking for.